# Preceding DIV relationships

Tags: html, css

I am new to the world of coding as well as CSS and am confused by the relationships each div tag has with its predecessor or parent. For example, my code is as below. A copy of the entire code is at the bottom of this question if that should make a difference.

Now if I were to zoom into just look at the container `<div id="content">`, is it safe to assume and say that its child `<div id="innercontent">` is only affected by `<div id="content">`. The same principle would hold that `<div id="content">` is affected by `<div id="header">`. Hence my CSS box model approach would be affected by each of the preceding `div` elements. Is that correct?

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="innerwrapper">

            <div id="header">
                <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.gif" width="150" height="96" alt="logo" /></div>

                <div id="topnav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>home</li>
                        <li>about</li>
                        <li>browse</li>
                        <li>faq</li>
                        <li>contact</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                <div id="innercontent">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at elementum neque vestibulum sollicitudin semper neque, vitae metus. Nibh ligula mi. Faucibus rutrum elit turpis, nec congue quam ipsum felis neque et, wisi amet, architecto eros congue. Maecenas suspendisse tellus arcu eget pharetra, rhoncus aenean sapien morbi nec arcu, vivamus aliquet lorem amet at, vestibulum purus sociis varius id. Imperdiet id magnis turpis beatae aliquet, vestibulum dolor nec eget eu cras lobortis, vel rerum, risus sed et, libero et non eros commodo. Taciti eu leo sollicitudin malesuada, nibh duis amet aenean, odio aptent ultrices. Tristique morbi nunc ullamcorper ut curabitur. Et a in ut sem varius, sem rutrum vehicula sem sed, at diam amet erat vel. Et sit in ante felis vitae sit.

                    Quam eget sed elit natoque velit, enim mauris mauris urna, integer amet tellus illo ipsum, dolor fermentum cursus enim mollis tristique porttitor. Non dignissim. Sit ligula leo tincidunt, justo ut ut placerat quisque non, risus nonummy. Ultrices mauris congue aliquam aliquam felis, at placerat, amet vestibulum dictumst pellentesque iaculis risus. Sem sed impedit nullam ultrices lorem aliquam, nulla tellus consequatur in ornare magna. Viverra amet pede in in ornare eu, id arcu. Justo mus suspendisse praesent et, amet mattis convallis ullamcorper felis, fermentum nibh at ac, ullamcorper ipsum auctor et maecenas, aliquam molestiae in qui. Massa elit suspendisse penatibus molestie libero dolor, non leo vitae, sollicitudin a, platea tristique iaculis, tortor augue non est. Ante rutrum quis pellentesque lacinia convallis non, vestibulum nibh nunc luctus nibh a, in amet, iaculis dui ornare pede laoreet eu. Cursus integer vehicula quis, justo eget purus mattis donec vestibulum nunc, nunc vel eros lectus.
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="rightcol"><img src="http://htmldog.com/r/logo.gif" width="140" height="91" alt="html" /></div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">footer</div>
    <div>
</body>
```

**ENTIRE CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />

    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <title>Example</title>

    <base href="" />

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />

    <style type="text/css" media="all">

    * {

        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

    }


    body {

        font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 0.8em;

    }


    #wrapper {

        /* background-image: url('images/bg-inner-page.gif'); */
        background-color: #808080;
        height: 200px;

    }

    #innerwrapper {

        width: 960px;
        overflow: auto;

    }

    #header {



    }

    #logo {

        float: left;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 50px;
        background-color: gray;

    }

    #topnav {

        float: left;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-left:30px;
        color: #ffffff;

    }

    #topnav ul {

        word-spacing: 10px;

    }

    #topnav ul li {

        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;

    }

    #content {

        clear: both;

    }

    #innercontent {

        float: left;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 225px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: 400px;

    }


    #rightcol {

        float: left;
        margin-top: 125px;
        margin-left: 50px;
        width: 200px;

    }


    #footer {

        background-color: gray;

    }


    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="innerwrapper">

            <div id="header">
                <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.gif" width="150" height="96" alt="logo" /></div>

                <div id="topnav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>home</li>
                        <li>about</li>
                        <li>browse</li>
                        <li>faq</li>
                        <li>contact</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                <div id="innercontent">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, at elementum neque vestibulum sollicitudin semper neque, vitae metus. Nibh ligula mi. Faucibus rutrum elit turpis, nec congue quam ipsum felis neque et, wisi amet, architecto eros congue. Maecenas suspendisse tellus arcu eget pharetra, rhoncus aenean sapien morbi nec arcu, vivamus aliquet lorem amet at, vestibulum purus sociis varius id. Imperdiet id magnis turpis beatae aliquet, vestibulum dolor nec eget eu cras lobortis, vel rerum, risus sed et, libero et non eros commodo. Taciti eu leo sollicitudin malesuada, nibh duis amet aenean, odio aptent ultrices. Tristique morbi nunc ullamcorper ut curabitur. Et a in ut sem varius, sem rutrum vehicula sem sed, at diam amet erat vel. Et sit in ante felis vitae sit.

                    Quam eget sed elit natoque velit, enim mauris mauris urna, integer amet tellus illo ipsum, dolor fermentum cursus enim mollis tristique porttitor. Non dignissim. Sit ligula leo tincidunt, justo ut ut placerat quisque non, risus nonummy. Ultrices mauris congue aliquam aliquam felis, at placerat, amet vestibulum dictumst pellentesque iaculis risus. Sem sed impedit nullam ultrices lorem aliquam, nulla tellus consequatur in ornare magna. Viverra amet pede in in ornare eu, id arcu. Justo mus suspendisse praesent et, amet mattis convallis ullamcorper felis, fermentum nibh at ac, ullamcorper ipsum auctor et maecenas, aliquam molestiae in qui. Massa elit suspendisse penatibus molestie libero dolor, non leo vitae, sollicitudin a, platea tristique iaculis, tortor augue non est. Ante rutrum quis pellentesque lacinia convallis non, vestibulum nibh nunc luctus nibh a, in amet, iaculis dui ornare pede laoreet eu. Cursus integer vehicula quis, justo eget purus mattis donec vestibulum nunc, nunc vel eros lectus.
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="rightcol"><img src="http://htmldog.com/r/logo.gif" width="140" height="91" alt="html" /></div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">footer</div>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by affected?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question.  It seems though that you are having some problems with specificity.  This should help: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: @Pablo Rodda Donate/rmlumley - My question is regarding when making changes to one element how it affects subsequent elements.

Comment: that depends, if you use the float or display properties, that will change the way your element gets displayed

Comment: @Pablo Rodda Donate - Thanks. How do you identify which element is being affected by which property or element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is strutured into what is known as the Document Object Model http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model .

Child divs are affected only by its parent elements (or any grandparent further up). However, when you start floating elements around, as your example shows, you may find that elements outside of their container start to interfere.

On the screen this can cause chaos as the elements push each other around to align, however, the DOM will always remain structured, independent of any css.

Comment: Thanks. When you say grandfather, I assume this would only be the case if the preceding parent has no properties and values. Is that correct?

Comment: When other elements affect float elements, how do you identify which element is affecting it?

Comment: If the grandparent had a property font="Arial", and the parent had a property font="Helvetica", then the child would render its font as Helvetica. If the parent did not have a font="Helvetica", then the child would render its font Arial. It inherits like this all the up to the root html element.

Comment: I've never found an easy way to identity which elements are messing up others with css. I just strip the html layout away a piece at a time until I see things working as expected, then I start adding the parts I've stripped back in until the problem occurs. You can try adding border: 1px solid red; to all your floating elements to see exactly what areas they are filling, then just remove it once you are happy.

Comment: Thanks. Started to make sense.